# Which is my Xcode version?

Tags: xcode

How can I determine which version of Xcode is currently installed in my OSX system?

Ideally, I would also like to determine it programatically from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If Xcode is running, the version and build number can be obtained from the “Xcode > About Xcode” menu. Alternatively, you can obtain this information by typing on a terminal:

```
$ /usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
```